# Does driver.lockScreen method works?

Tags: appium

I have called `driver.lockScreen(20);` in my script and then calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 26");` to unlock screen.

But problem is, as I have specified 20 sec wait for lock screen, device is not getting locked for 20 sec. My next statement keyevent 26 is unlocking the device as soon as device is locked.

So

- why we are providing 20 sec parameter?

Comment: You can add the details `/**
     * Lock the device (bring it to the lock screen) for a given number of
     * seconds
     *
     * @param seconds
     *            number of seconds to lock the screen for
     */
    public void lockScreen(int seconds) {
        execute(LOCK, ImmutableMap.of("seconds", seconds));
    }`  from the AppiumDriver.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an open issue on Github https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/315

Below are the updates (fixes) mentioned on Github for lockScreen bug:

- The `_AppiumDriver.lockScreen(int seconds)_` is deprecated now.
- AndroidDriver: `_lockDevice()_ and _unlockDevice()_` were added
- IOSDriver: `_lockDevice(int seconds)_` was added